# iCloud Notes on Macbook not synchronising with iPad/iPhone IOS 9.0.2

Tags: macbook-pro

After upgrading to IOS 9.0.2, I just realised the iCloud notes on my Macbook didn't syn with my iPad and iPhone.

Despite removing my iCloud Notes from my Macbook, rebooting my Mac and signing into my Apple ID again, the error still persists.

Comment: Did you upgrade OS X to El Capitan?
Notes in iOS 9 sync with Notes on El Capitan

Comment: i didnt upgrade my OS X to EI Capitan cause i read some reviews and seems there are some bugs on EI Capitan.  no idea at all why the error occured.  My iphone, ipad and Macbook got the same OS version i.e. IOS 9.0.2. Later i tried to update a note with my Macbook but using gmail, the message syn and i could find the newly added msg on my ipad.  Just the icloud not from my Macbook doesnt syn with my iphone / ipad.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may be dependent on whether this button still exists in the Notes app on your iPhone, & whether your Mac has been updated to El Capitan or not...

[image]

If you have upgraded Notes on the iPhone on iOS 9, then you must be on El Capitan for them to be compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  My iphone, ipad and Macbook got the same OS version i.e. IOS 9.0.2.  Couldnt find any 'upgrade' button.  Later i tried to update a note with my Macbook but using gmail, the message syn and i could find the newly added msg on my ipad...